# How to add border-corner-radius only on left side of the button with jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code in my HTML:

```
<div id="ot-lang-src">
<button id="rerun"></button>
<button id="select">Choose a language</button>
<ul id="ui-menu-left">                                                      
</ul>
</div>
```

I use jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom I have downloaded. Problem is with border-radius.
I'm trying to add border radius only on left side of the button. Border on right side stays 0px.

Jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js added *.ui-corner-all* class to button on page load which means border for all four corner is 2px. I tried to remove *.ui-corner-all* class and to add *.ui-corner-left* class:

```
$("button#rerun").removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-left");
```

and it doesn't work. I have this code in jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css:

```
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px; -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 2px; border-top-left-radius: 2px; }
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-tr { -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px; -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 2px; border-top-right-radius: 2px; }
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-bl { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; }
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br { -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 2px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; }
```

Is this right way to solve this problem, and how to remove *.ui-corner-all* class?
Is it better way for this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Increase the corner radius to, for instance 8px, and you'll probably notice that it works.
[Fiddle test here](http://jsfiddle.net/b3n3G/1/)

```
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl {
    -moz-border-radius-top-left: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: That not works for me. Button already has class .ui-corner-all and so 4 rounded corners. I wont right side of the button with border 0px. and left side with 2px for example. Problem is I can't remove .ui-corner-all class, actually I don't now how. Your suggestion works but that is only because you dont have preveously mentioned class. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your button in the example in your code does not have any class. If you add the .ui-corner-all to the button probably you'll see it work or else, you're not posting all the required information to get the solution to your problem.

Comment: Mario I'm working with jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom. That means I have downloaded custom version of jquey-ui. I olready have custom.js file, and as I said custom.js file automatically added .ui-coner-all to the button. And with this code: $("button#rerun").removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-left"); I can not remove that class. That is the problem.

Comment: Probably that code is running before any other code is adding the class. Check the flow of your scripts and see if you're not trying to remove a class that hasn't been created yet. I mean, check if the addClass() is really being called before you try to removeClass(). To troubleshoot, place the remove class at the very bottom of your page (and on document ready), just to check that it really removes the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `border-radius` property same as this rule:

```
border-radius: top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left;
```

For example:

```
border-radius: 0px 10px 20px 30px;
-ms-border-radius: 0px 10px 20px 30px;  /* For make it compatible with IE 8 */
```

If you added reference of jQuery to your page you can do exactly as same as what I done in here [Changing border radius customizable](https://jsfiddle.net/Milad_Rashidi/ownv79mr/#&togetherjs=DVvsvIEt9c)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding your own class to the button and make sure the CSS that defines that class is loaded after the JQuery UI CSS definitions.